# What is --user =

Tags: command-line, debian

I found the following statement from mysql doc:

```
scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

I'm wondering what is '--user=mysql' from the above? The statement has no command at all, so I'm confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man mysql_install_db`](http://man.he.net/man1/mysql_install_db):

> ```
> --user=user_name
>
>        The login user name to use for running mysqld. Files and
>        directories created by mysqld will be owned by this user. You must
>        be root to use this option. By default, mysqld runs using your
>        current login name and files and directories that it creates will
>        be owned by you.
> ```